# add to cart button is not responding

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

my add to cart button is not responding. I have applied javascript on my add to cart button, In the cart button, I have assigned attribute i.e data-product the value that is {{product.id}}.

```js
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (var i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
  updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var productId = this.dataset.product
    var action = this.dataset.action
    console.log('productId:', productId, 'action:', action)

  })
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title fw-bold text-uppercase">{{product.name}}</h5>
  <p class="card-text">
    <h4 style="font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.3rem;
            opacity: 0.8;">$ {{product.price}} </h4>
  </p>
  <button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">ADD TO CART</button>
</div>
</div>
```

The console is not showing anything even though I click on Add to Cart button several times

Comment: instead of `getElementsByClassName` do `querySelectorAll` and instead of `for` loop use `forEach`.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you intend with your JS code. `getElementsByClassName` returns an Object of HTML Collection not an array. `length` would return the amount of elements within an array but not an Object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getElementsByClassName` use `querySelectorAll` beacuse as [@tacoshy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14072420/tacoshy) stated `getElementsByClassName` returns an object of HTML Collection not an array. Also `length` would return the amount of elements within an array but not an object.

```js
const updateBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.update-cart')

updateBtns.forEach((updateBtn) => {
    updateBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        var productId = updateBtn.dataset.product
        var action = updateBtn.dataset.action

        console.log('productId:', productId, 'action:', action)
    })
})
```